# Why is $\frak m$ solvable?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Take a real semisimple Lie algebra, $\frak g$ with Iwasawa decomposition $\frak g = k \oplus a \oplus n$.  Let $\mathfrak m :=Z_\frak k(a)$ be the centralizer in $\frak k$ of $\frak a$.  I take it from some things I've read that $\frak m \oplus a \oplus n$ is solvable. This is clear to me except for the bracket of $\frak m$ with itself.  It seems like it reduces to $\frak m$ being solvable.  Why is $\frak m$ solvable?

Comment: If $\mathfrak{g}$ is compact, is not $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{k}$ and $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{n} = 0$, hence $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{g} $, in particular not solvable?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg huh. good point. I ask because I thought $\frak m \oplus a \oplus n$ corresponded to a Borel subgroup, which I think is supposed to be a maximal solvable subgroup. But clearly something is wrong with that.

Comment: My guesses (not really checked) are: $\mathfrak{m} \oplus \mathfrak{a} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$ is parabolic. It is a Borel iff $\mathfrak{m}$ is abelian (in other words, = its own center $\mathfrak{z}$), iff $\mathfrak{g}$ is quasisplit. In general we have $\mathfrak{m}$ reductive with radical $\mathfrak{z}$ and Levi subalgebra $[\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{m}]$, which is also the Levi part of the parabolic. -- One can choose a maximal abelian subalgebra $\mathfrak{c}$ (necess. containing $\mathfrak{z}$) of $\mathfrak{m}$, then $\mathfrak{c} \oplus \mathfrak{a} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$ is still solvable.

Comment: (cont'd). $\mathfrak{c} \oplus \mathfrak{a}$ should be a Cartan subalgebra, so $\mathfrak{c} \oplus \mathfrak{a} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$ would be a maximal solvable subalgebra; but in general not a Borel as it does not stay maximal solvable after complexification, except in the quasisplit case $\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{c} = \mathfrak{z}$. -- In any case, the radical of the parabolic $\mathfrak{m} \oplus \mathfrak{a} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$ is just $\mathfrak{z} \oplus \mathfrak{a} \oplus \mathfrak{n}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Fantastic. Just the explanation I was looking for. Thanks very much.